# Cannot understand uplevel command in TCL

Tags: tcl

I am having some problems understanding the use of uplevel in TCL. I am reading Brent Welch's Practical programming in TCL and Tk and there is an example in uplevel that I cannot understand. Here it is:

```
proc lassign {valueList args} {
  if {[llength $args] == 0} {
    error "wrong # args:lassign list varname ?varname...?"
  }
  if {[llength $valueList] == 0} {
    #Ensure one trip through the foreach loop
    set valueList [List {}]
  }
  uplevel 1 [list foreach $args $valueList {break}]
  return [lrange $valueList [llength $args] end]
}
```

Can someone please explain it to me? The explanation in the book does not help me enough :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `uplevel` command executes a command (or in fact a script) in another scope than that of the current procedure. In particular, in this case it is `uplevel 1` which means “execute in caller”. (You can also execute in the global scope with `uplevel #0`, or in other places too such as the caller's caller with `uplevel 2` but that's *really* rare.)

Explaining the rest of that line: the use of the `list` here is as a way of constructing a substitution-free command, which consists of four words, `foreach`, the contents of the `args` variable, the contents of `valueList` variable, and `break` (which didn't actually need to be in braces). That will assign a value from the front of `valueList` to each variable listed in `args`, and then stop, and it will do so in the context of the caller.

Overall, the procedure works just like the built-in `lassign` in 8.5 (assuming a non-empty input list and variable list), except slower because of the complexity of swapping between scopes and things like that.

Comment: In 8.6, we managed to find a use for `uplevel #1` with coroutines. This was considered to be the first practical use _ever_ for that particular form, even though it has been legal for decades.

Comment: The *#<number>* syntax is described thus: "If *level* consists of # followed by a number then the number gives an absolute level number." http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/uplevel.htm

Comment: @DonalFellows Don't `tailcall` the top `coroutine` stack.

Answer (score 5):

```
proc a {} {
  set x a
  uplevel 3 {set x Hi}
  puts "x in a = $x"
}
proc b {} {
  set x b
  a
  puts "x in b = $x"
}
proc c {} {
  set x c
  b
  puts "x in c = $x"
}
set x main
c
puts "x in main == $x"
```

here the most inside method a will be in level 0 and b in level ,c in level 2 and main program will be in level 3 so in proc a if i change the value of level then i can change the value of variable x of any proc be it a,b,c or main proc from method "a" itself.
try changing level to 3,2,1,0 and see the magic putput.